# Как с помощью innerHTML изменить слово и нажав еще раз на событие вернуть его в прежнее значение

Tags: javascript, dom

Я недавно начала изучать `js`, и вот когда дело дошло к `DOM` я столкнулась с одной маленькой проблемой, которую не могу решить. Имееться код:

```js
function f1(){
  var a = document.getElementByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML = "home";
}
```

```html
 <p onclick="f1()">car</p>
```

Тогда слово **"car"** измениться на слово **"home"**. Но, что если я хочу при нажатии на тег `<p>` так же изменить слово на **"home"**, но когда нажму на тег еще раз, хочу что бы он изменилься обратно на "car". Может для вас это никакой проблемы не составит, но я вот уже час не могу понять, как это сделать. Буду благодарна за ответ.

Comment: Для хранения пользовательской информации лучше использовать [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) атрибуты.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var a = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
var text = a.innerText;

function f1() {

  if (a.innerText == 'home') {
    a.innerText = text;
  } else {
    a.innerText = 'home';
  }

}
```

```html
<p onclick="f1()">car</p>
```

```
document.getElementByTagName("p")[0].innerHTML - добавьте букву s после "Element"
```

Comment: Это помогло, но "innerText" не поддерживается в Firefox. Можно ли его как-то заменить?

Comment: @Elvira Kukhtaruk, просто замените "innerText" на "innerHTML"

Comment: Спасибо большое, возможно ли то же сделать с бекграундом в диве  вместо текста? Нужно заменить innerText на src ?

Comment: @ElviraKukhtaruk innerText поддерживается в Firefox. Эпоха браузерных войн давно прошла.

Answer (score 0):

В функцию `f1` передаём ссылку на элемент, по которому кликнули.

```js
function f1(element){
  console.log('Наш элемент: ', element);
  if ( element.textContent === 'car') {
    element.textContent = 'home';
  } else {
    element.textContent = 'car';
  }
}
```

```html
<p onclick="f1(this)">car</p>
```

> **UPD:** В вашем коде ошибка. Вместо `getElementByTagName` необходимо написать `getElementsByTagName`. После написания любого скрипта, смотрите консоль броузера!

Answer (score 0):

Лучше заранее обозначить все возможные варианты содержимого тега, чем сверять каждый раз его текущее значение:

```js
var values = ['car', 'home', 'whatever'];
var current = 0;

function f1(element){
  if (++current == values.length) current = 0;
  element.textContent = values[current];
}
```

```html
<p onclick="f1(this)">car</p>
```